# Why is ElasticBeanstalk ignoring my .ebignore file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to prevent my static files from being included in the source bundle uploaded with elasticbeanstalk. I'm not sure where exactly my .ebignore file belongs.

```
Main_Direction
 /.ebextension
 /.elasticbeanstalk
 /Actual_Project
   //....
```

I put the .ebignore file in the Actual_Project directory. However, this doesn't seem to work because I'm getting the following error.

```
ERROR: Application version cannot be any larger than 512MB
```

My .ebignore file is very simple:

```
static/*
```

I've also tried static without the asterix and trailing slash.

I'm using: **EB CLI 3.6.2 (Python 3.4.3)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seems like your directory structure is a bit off. the beanstalk files belong in the root directory of your project, which in your case is `Actual_Project`. Move them there. 
As a side note, I use `.gitignore` instead of `.ebignore`, as beanstalk will use it if `.ebignore` is missing. It too belongs to the root dir (right next to the `.git` folder)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to add the `.git` entry to the `.ebignore` file. After adding it, I was able to upload the app archive.